# Count lines ending in "*"

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have several files in a directory with this kind of content:

```
Wood *
Nails
Large Hammer *
```

Some names have a star after them, some don't. I have multiple files with such content. In each file a product may or may not have a **single** star next to it.
I need to make a bash script to count the number of star occurrences for each individual product in all the files. For example, the output needs to be like this:

```
Wood 12
Yellow Lamps 6
Nails 4
...
```

Which means that in all the files it found 12x a star next to Wood, 6x a star next to the lamps, etc...

It's pretty easy to parse it in C, but I don't want a binary to run. I want a shell script, and I'm not as versatile with grep and awk, which I'm sure I need here.

I know how to count the stars per se, but I'm not sure how to track which star count belongs to which product.

Comment: What about `Wood * moretext`? should be considered `Wood` as another occurrence?  Or what about `Wood buzz *`? `Wood buzz` should be considered as another occurrence too>

Comment: After the star there is no more text. An occurence of 'Wood buzz *' should not count toward 'Wood'.  It should be it's own product.  'Wood buzz'  /= 'Wood'

Comment: If a product had no star in any file, say 'Lemon', should it be excluded from the output or should it be present as 'Lemon 0'?

Comment: If you want help writing a script to count occurrences of strings then provide sample input/output that has multiple occurrences of strings. If you want help writing a script that acts on the appearance or absence of some string/character (e.g. `*`) then provide sample input/output that includes some lines that do and some that don't have that string/character. We can't test a potential solution using the example you provided where every string from the input appears in the output, there's only 1 occurrence of each string you want counted, and the output counts don't come from the input.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify: Can there be stars at any other position?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this, with one [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '$NF=="*"{$NF=""; arr[$0]++}END{for (i in arr) print i arr[i]}' ./*
```

- `$NF` is the latest string separated by space(s) by default
- the main trick is to create an associative named `arr`ay with the current words as *key* and incrementing as *value*
- at the `END` we iterate over the `arr`ay to `print` each keys/values

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) one-liner:

```
perl -anE '
    if ($F[-1] eq "*") {
        $k = join " ", @F[0..@F-2];
        $a->{$k}++
    }
    END{say "$_ $a->{$_}" for keys %$a}
' ./*
```

The `-a` is the *split* mode in `@F` default array

Comment: That's better!  +1. In this case it should be `*` instead of `file` because the user has several files.

Comment: Or `**/*` if the OP has subdirectories.

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
sed -n 's/[[:blank:]]*\*$//p' ./* |
  LC_ALL=C sort |
  LC_ALL=C uniq -c |
  sort -rn
```

Which removes the `<blanks>*` at the end of the lines (and `p`rints only the lines where there has been such a substitution) and use `sort | uniq -c` to count the unique lines (in the C locale for it to be a byte-to-byte comparison).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this can affect the performance (if you have very larges files I would think this command should be slow):

```bash
grep -Fh '*' | tr -s ' ' | sort | uniq -c
```

More portable:

```bash
grep -Fh '*' * 2>/dev/null | tr -s ' ' | sort | uniq -c
```

And if you have sub-directories with more files you want to search inside:

```bash
grep -Fh '*' **/* 2>/dev/null | tr -s ' ' | sort | uniq -c | sed 's/.$//'
```

Or to avoid using `2>/dev/null`:

```bash
find . -type f -exec grep -Fh '*' {} + | tr -s ' ' | sort | uniq -c | sed 's/.$//'
```

The section `grep -Fh '*'` means that will match any line which has a `*` at the end of this one. `-h` suppress printing the filenames whose matches the pattern and `-F` is for using literal strings (the '*' behaves as a string and not as pattern).
About `tr -s ' '` I'm removing repeated spaces between every line, for example having this:

```
Need *
Word   buzz *
Need *
More   *
More *
Word   *
More   *
More *
Word   *
Word   *
Need *
More *
```

the `tr` command will parse it to:

```
Need *
Word buzz *
Need *
More *
More *
Word *
More *
More *
Word *
Word *
Need *
More *
```

The content above is piped to `sort` to have this output:

```
More *
More *
More *
More *
More *
Need *
Need *
Need *
Word *
Word *
Word *
Word buzz *
```

And finally with `uniq -c` I'm prefixing lines by the number of occurrences of every word which is what you want.

**The sort command is important, if you do not use it, the expected result will be different**

According to the output above, the final output (by using `uniq -c`) will be:

```
5 More *
3 Need *
3 Word *
1 Word buzz *
```

If you want to remove the `*` you can pipe to `sed` to remove the last character or `*`:

```bash
grep -Fh '*'  * | tr -s ' ' | sort | uniq -c | sed 's/.$//'
#or
grep -Fh '*' * | tr -s ' ' | sort | uniq -c | sed 's/\*//'
```

I think and hope there are better ways to achieve that, because here I'm using several commands to get the desired output. So as I said it may result in slow performance.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks so much! Edited accordingly. I did not know about that, that's  a very good observation and information. Actually I do not know much about POSIX compliant, so I'm not sure if the code I use is good for portability or not. I  appreciate these comments :).

Comment: You're welcome. FYI `grep -R` and `tr --squeeze-repeats` aren't portable (use `-s` instead of `--squeeze-repeats`, and IMHO no-one should ever use `-R` - use **find** to find files, not grep, the GNU guys really broke with UNIX philosophy by giving grep options to do the same things as `find` already does).

Comment: @EdMorton thanks again! I edited to include `tr -s` instead. About `grep -R` I will consider for future answers/uses (to avoid expand the script here, which is already some large to solve the problem). I never thought that `grep -R` was not portable , it surprises me.

Comment: Yeah `-R` is a poorly-thought-out GNUism. The UNIX philosphy is to have  tools that do 1 thing and do it well working together when necessary. The tool to **find** files is named `find`, and the tool to **g/re/p** (the `ed` commands to Globally match a Regular Expression in a file and Print the result) is named `grep`. Giving grep the ability to also find files absolutely breaks that philosophy - why not give find, sed, awk, cut, tr and every other tool options to find files too? Why not also give grep options to replace text or sort it's output or translate characters? It's a nasty mistake.

Comment: @EdMorton that's a very good point about UNIX philosophy. Unless when answering to posts here some people have portability problems. For example in my case I use the **gnu tools** but sometimes the user who made the question use MacOS and therefore might have portability problems. What about `sed --posix or awk --posix`? If I use them in Linux am I guaranteed to use the same sed,awk script on macOS?

Comment: No because in cases where POSIX doesn't define behavior GNU might do X while MacOS does Y. For example the meaning of `print > "foo" 17` in awk is undefined by POSIX - GNU awk, with or without `--posix`, will treat it like `print > ("foo" 17)` but MacOS would treat it like `(print > "foo") 17` and report it as a syntax error. All you CAN guarantee that `--posix` does is disable GNU extensions e.g. `gensub()` or multi-char RS because those things have a different, defined meaning to POSIX.

Comment: @EdMorton good explanation! Thanks a lot! All this is useful :).

Comment: The question starts with "I have several files in a directory ...", so I assume recursive search is not required. You can also use `grep -h '\*' * | ...`

Comment: @Bodo Nice suggestion! I updated the answer using that instead of `grep -R` which as EdMorton said is not protable. It would be necessary `-R` if the OP had sub-directories with more files but I used `**/*` instead of `recursive grep`.

Comment: If the OP had sub-directories you should use `find . -type f -exec grep -h '\*' {} +` instead of `grep -Rh '\*'`, there's simply no need for `grep` to be doing `find`'s job. I just noticed the grep should really be `grep -Fh '*'` rather than `grep -h '\*'`.

Comment: @EdMorton I  really had forgotten `-F` option in `grep`. Since I usually don't use it but here it's the best choice. I added an example with `find` too. Using `grep text **/*` or `grep text *` seems good but it produces warnings/stderr for directories.

Comment: There's a grep option to ignore directories to avoid getting those messages (`-d skip`), but AFAIK that's just a GNU-ism.

Comment: @EdMorton I've used `-D skip` for skipping the other type of files, but I had no idea about `-d` option for skipping for directories!

Answer (score 2):

Using bash or just awk is recommended, but I liked the challenge of doing it in (GNU) sed.

```
s:  *: :g
/\*$/!s:$: :
G
s:([^\n]+) (\*?)(.*\n)\1 (\**)\n:\3\1 \4\2\n:
s:^\n::
h;$!d
s:\n$::
:u2d
    s:\*:<<123456789*01>:m
    s:(.)<.*\1(\**.).*>:\2:m
tu2d
```

I tested with the two input files below (vim display); first one from Edgar Magallon's answer:

```
Need *         |Need
Word   buzz *  |Word   buzz
Need *         |Need
More   *       |More *
More *         |More *
Word   *       |Word
More   *       |More *
More *         |More *
Word   *       |Word
Word   *       |Word
Need *         |Need
More *         |More *
~              |~
~              |~
input1          input2
```

**Result:**

```
~$ sed -rf script.sed input1 input2
Word 3
More 10
Word buzz 1
Need 3
```